# Фиксация блока по координате Y

Tags: html, css, javascript

Как зафиксировать блок только по одной координате? Мне нужно, чтобы фиксация была по оси Y... прошу дать полный ответ, а не что-то вроде используйте JS или тому подобные ответы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Была такая же проблема, нужно было по вертикали закрепить жёстко, а вот по горизонтали элемент должен был остаться плавающим. Я решил с помощью яваскрипта. Если нужно, выложу код.

Comment: да, выложи код))

Comment: ребят) ответьте)

Comment: @Lgunchik скиньте свой код!

Answer (score 2):

Что-то понять не могу в чем сложность. Задайте блоку **position: fixed;** и для позиционирования по вертикали **top: 100px;**. Вот и будет он зафиксирован по оси **Y**
[Вот и примерчик вам](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/eKbmg/1/), а то как-то грозно в вопросе звучит "*...прошу дать полный ответ, а не, что-то вроде...*"

```
<style>
#block {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
}
</style>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: ты не понял проблемы!!!

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивалась с этой проблемой. Здесь действительно без JavaScript не обойтись.
Создаете div со свойствами `position: fixed; left: 0;`. Добавляете слушатель на scroll event вашего документа, в котором задаете фиксированному диву отступ слева противоположный отступу прокрутки `yourDiv.left = -document.scrollLeft`.

Для обратной задачи, то есть фиксации блока только по оси Х, замените все `left` на `top`.